# Handling two insert queries as a single transaction in an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I am trying to handle two insert queries as a single transaction in Oracle.

I have tried the following

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (27, TO_DATE('19-Jun-2018 05:47', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'), '622222222222', 167, 15454015, '335218', '5623125454');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('145218', TO_DATE('19-Jun-2018 05:47', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'), ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('19-Jun-2018 05:47', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'),1));
END;
```

But this gives me an error

Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Please post your code, so that can help on the issue

Comment: edited question and added code

Comment: Could you please add your table scripts ?

Comment: The insert queries work by themselves, it's just that they don't work after trying to handle them as a single transaction

Comment: Which editor are you using ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me using either SQL\*Plus or PL/SQL Developer. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your which columns you want to insert values. Try below.

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1,
                       COL2,
                       COL3,
                       COL4,
                       COL5,
                       COL6,
                       COL7)
        VALUES (27,
                TO_DATE ('19-Jun-2018 05:47', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'),
                '622222222222',
                167,
                15454015,
                '335218',
                '5623125454');

   INSERT INTO TABLE2 (COL1, COL2, COL3)
           VALUES (
                     '145218',
                     TO_DATE ('19-Jun-2018 05:47', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'),
                     ADD_MONTHS (
                        TO_DATE ('19-Jun-2018 05:47', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'),
                        1));
COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain SQL, there is no BEGIN TRANSACTION statement in Oracle SQL (BEGIN is PL/SQL keyword to start a PL/SQL block only).

A transaction begins with the first writing in the database and ends with COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Example:

```
TEST@DB0>truncate table t1;

Table truncated.

TEST@DB0>truncate table t2;

Table truncated.

TEST@DB0>insert into t1 values(1, 'ONE');

1 row created.

TEST@DB0>insert into t2 values(2, 'TWO');

1 row created.

TEST@DB0>rollback;

Rollback complete.

TEST@DB0>select * from t1;

no rows selected

TEST@DB0>select * from t2;

no rows selected

TEST@DB0>insert into t1 values(1, 'ONE');

1 row created.

TEST@DB0>insert into t2 values(2, 'TWO');

1 row created.

TEST@DB0>commit;

Commit complete.

TEST@DB0>select * from t1;

    X1 Y1
---------- ----------
     1 ONE

TEST@DB0>select * from t2;

    X2 Y2
---------- ----------
     2 TWO

TEST@DB0>
```